# I in confuse about uk spouse visa n baby uk passport

Tags: visas, passports, uk-citizens

I am an indonesian citizen n my husband is uk citizen. We want to apply our uk first baby passport we have all document to apply. Form,pic,our marriage certificate,our birth certificate but he need one more longg birth certificate  is there anyone here ever apply for long birth certificate? Can u tell us how to apply it online or as fast as we can get that?and what document need to send with the form ? As i readed they just ask me to fill the form n send the the address written below the form. I have another question as i am confusing about what my husband talking about spouse visa can bring  1 kid if my husband prove his income about £ 22.500. He thought if he can show that income then he just need apply 1 visa for 2 (me n our baby) is it true? As i checked so manytime no rules said that... please give me answer so i can screenshot the answer n send to my husband.

Comment: A spouse visa is for immigration. If you are planning to immigrate then you should ask at [Expatriates.SE].

Comment: You  have a lot of questions. This forum works better if you focus on one question at a time. You may be able to find answers with existing questions by searching on each question either here or on [expatriates.se]. If the baby gets a UK passport (even by descent), I think only you would need a visa, but I am not sure.